# How to validate <aui:select> in a Liferay Form?

Tags: java, validation, liferay, portlet, alloy-ui

In View.jsp I created a form by using . there are some inputs and 3 select-box on it, actually I want to validate all of them. for inputs I used  but I don't know how can I validate my

Actually I want to validate these three  :

1. `<aui:select id="birthday_day" name="birthday_day">`
2. `<aui:select id="birthday_month" name="birthday_month">`
3. `<aui:select id="birthday_year" name="birthday_year">`

This is my view.jsp

```
        <portlet:actionURL var="myUrl">
    </portlet:actionURL>
<aui:form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<%= myUrl %>" method="POST" name="fm">
 <table border="0" bgcolor=#ccFDDEE>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" align="center"><b>Recruiment Form</b></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" align="center"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><b>First Name:<span>*</span></b></td>
            <td>
                <aui:input name="fname" type="text">
                    <aui:validator name="required"/>
                </aui:input>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td><b>Last Name:<span>*</span></b></td>
            <td>
                <aui:input name="lname" type="text">
                    <aui:validator name="required"/>
                </aui:input>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><b>Father Name:<span>*</span></b></td>
            <td>
                <aui:input name="father_name" type="text">
                    <aui:validator name="required"/>
                </aui:input>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><b>Birth Date:<span>*</span></b></td>
            <td>
                <aui:select id="birthday_day" name="<portlet:namespace/>birthday_day">
                    <aui:option value="0">روز</aui:option>
                    <%
                        for(int i=1;i<=31;i++) {
                    %>
                    <aui:option value="<%=i%>"><%=i%></aui:option>
                    <%
                        }
                    %>
                </aui:select>
                /
                <aui:select id="birthday_month" name="birthday_month">
                    <aui:option value="0">ماه</aui:option>
                    <%
                        String[] monthBirthDay = {"فروردین","اردیبهشت","خرداد","تیر","مرداد","شهریور","مهر","آبان","آذر","دی","بهمن","اسفند"};
                        for(int j=0;j<monthBirthDay.length;j++) {
                    %>
                    <aui:option value="<%=j+1%>"><%=monthBirthDay[j]%></aui:option>
                    <%
                        }
                    %>
                </aui:select>
                /
                <aui:select id="birthday_year" name="birthday_year">
                    <aui:option value="0">سال</aui:option>
                    <%
                        String[] yearBirthDay = {"1370","1369","1368","1367","1366","1365","1364"};
                        for(int j=0;j<yearBirthDay.length;j++) {
                    %>
                    <aui:option value="<%=yearBirthDay[j]%>"><%=yearBirthDay[j]%></aui:option>
                    <%
                        }
                    %>
                </aui:select>
            </td>
        </tr>
  </table>
</aui:form>
```

How can I solve this issue??????
Please guide me.

Comment: What kind of validation do you want to perform on select box?

Comment: @Felix Christy, Is it possible I use <aui:select> validation???????????

Comment: @Felix Christy, I don't know there are how many ways for validating????????? Can you guide me about it?????// Thanks in advance :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20548181/liferay-creating-a-new-type-of-aui-validator/20552287#20552287

Comment: @ParkashKumar, Thanks for your reply, It was usefull :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<aui:select showEmptyOption="true" name="select hospital name" required="true">

</aui:select>
```

THis may help you.

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?

Answer (score 1):

just assign an id to the aui:select tag

```
<aui:select inlineField="true" label="xxx" name="xxx" id="xxxId">
```

and then you can get the value with this (javascript + AUI)

```
var selectedVal = A.one('#<portlet:namespace/>xxxId').val();
```

with the selected value you can perform any kind of validation.